# Short syntax for multiple selectors of one HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="bar" />
</form>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bar">
</form>
```

And this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#form input[name=foo], input[name=bar]').change(function (){

    alert('foo');

  });

});
```

Now, if I check #form foo, 'foo' will be displayed. This happens not if I check the other checkbox "foo", but by both 'bar' checkboxes.

What I want is, that only the action will be recognized that was taken in the form with the id 'form'. I can do that by modifying this line to:

```
$('#form input[name=foo], #form input[name=bar]').change(function (){
```

I was just wondering if there is a 'short' syntax possibility?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would assign the same class for them and apply the jquery for that class like this:

```
$('#form .classname').change(function (){

    alert('foo');

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, not really shorter, but you can avoid using `#form` twice by doing:

```
$('#form').find('input[name=foo], input[name=bar]').change(function () {
```

Slightly shorter:

```
$('#form input').filter('[name=foo], [name=bar]').change(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use select the `#form` and then use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) on the element:

Example:

> $(document).ready(function () {
>
> ```
> $('#form').find('input[name=foo], input[name=bar]').change(function () {
>
>     alert('foo');
> });
>  });
> ```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/5LH7G/

Documentation find:

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector by attribute value :

```
$('form [name=foo], form [name=bar]').change(function (){
    alert('foo');
  });
```